# macrodef not conveying the exit status correctly

Tags: java, ant

I am calling an Ant task defined using `macrodef` but I find that the `fail` task's exit status is not properly conveyed to the shell.

The following is a SSCCE:

Ant file:

```
<project>

<macrodef name="ff">
    <sequential>
        <fail message="some failure" status="3"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<ff/>

</project>
```

Invocation:

```
$ ant 
Buildfile: /[...]/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
[...]build.xml:10: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[...]build.xml:5: some failure

Total time: 0 seconds
```

The build failed as expected; yet the exit status is not correct:

```
$ echo $?
1
```

I.e `Ant` exited with a status of 1 instead of 3. This only happens when the `fail` task is wrapped inside a `macrodef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An initial guess can be obtained from [the documentation of the `fail` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) regarding the `status` attribute:

> Exit using the specified status code; ***assuming the generated Exception is not caught***, the JVM will exit with this status.

That's exactly what's happening when using a macrodef: the `BuildException` that is thrown by the `fail` task to exit the build is being *caught* by the macrodef. Eventually some sort of a *wrapper exception* is thrown by the macrodef which swallows the exit code.

You can also see this from the exception stack trace when running Ant in debug mode:

**Using the macrodef:**

```
some failure
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Exit.execute(Exit.java:164)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Notice the method called by the `MacroInstance` class (line 398) in the stacktrace. By looking at the Ant code at this line, you can see a `try-catch` block that catches the exception thrown by `fail`:

```
try {
    c.perform();
} catch (BuildException ex) {
    if (this.macroDef.getBackTrace()) {
        throw ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ex, getLocation());
    }

    ex.setLocation(getLocation());
    throw ex;
}
```

In the `catch` block, a *new exception* is thrown in the following line:

```
throw ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ex, getLocation());
```

which causes the exit code of the original `BuildException` to be ignored.

Taking a step further, we can see that this wrapper exception is thrown if `this.macroDef.getBackTrace()` is enabled. Therefore, the solution to the problem is to set the `backtrace` parameter to `false` in the macrodef:

```
<macrodef name="ff" backtrace="false">
    <sequential>
        <fail message="some failure" status="3"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```